# Explorer crashes on TaskView

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, crash, task-view

Since a few days my explorer crashes and restarts everytime I open the TaskView (Win + Tab).
Anytime else the system is stable.
It shows the same behavior when using the task bar button right next to the windows-button.

Eventlog tracks all these crashes and shows:

- path to faulty application: C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe
- path to faulty module: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll

Furthermore I cannot see any more hint.

When starting in secure mode (with network), pressing Win+Tab causes not an instant crash and restart of explorer. Instead the TaskView freezes and does not allow any input.
An error occures in the background which tells:
"The system detected an overrun of a stack-based buffer in this application."

This only happens in secure mode.

I already tried:

- Windows Update to 21H2 - 19044
- DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth
- DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
- renaming HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\BannerStore to BannerStoreOld

What else can I try? Of course, in my opinion I didn't made any groundbraking changes, no installs or uninstalls etc.
There is also no high sensitive anti virus or smth.

Comment: This only happens in secure mode.   .......   Make a new test Windows User Profile (Account). Log into the new Windows Account and test Task View. See if that works. You may have a damaged Windows Account.

Comment: @John Unfortuantely not, a fresh account behaves in exact the same way with the exact same error in the event log.

Comment: If that is the case, try a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link.  Use the option to Keep Everything to begin with.   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: @John This for the moment solved the problem by getting out of the installation process with a downgraded version 21H1 - 19043
Thanks for this help, I hope MS will not destroy this feature again with the next update attempt ;)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was (maybe temporarily) solved by the repair installation of windows10. This ended up in a downgrade from (19044 to 19043) compared to the build before.
During this hassle I realized, that my installation was registered for the insider program, so probably this is a hint for someone else who encounters such issues.

Hopefully, the final version of the 19044 build will be released without this issue.

Thanks a lot to @John

Comment: I have a very similar issue. Explorer crashes around once in every 20 times when clicking on Task View (Edition: Windows 10 Pro, Version: 21H2, OS Build: 19044.1766). Has the issue been fixed for you with a newer update of Windows 10?